# Вся программа работает нормально, но на 9 тесте выдает runtime error. Какая может быть ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Это мой код, все тесты проходит нормально, но потом появляется ошибка

```
str1 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
str2 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
all_lin = []
for i in range(str1[0]):
    all_lin.extend([0] * (str1[1] - str2[i]))
for i in range(1, str1[0] + 1):
    all_mno = []
    for j in range(1, len(all_lin) + 1):
        mno = i * j
        if mno > len(all_lin):
            break
        else:
            all_mno.append(mno)
    if str2[i - 1] > 0:
        for y in range(1, str2[i - 1] + 1):
            all_lin.insert(all_mno[y - 1] - 1, i)
yv = all_lin[-str1[2]::-str1[2]]

print(*[yv.count(m) for m in range(1, str1[0] + 1)])
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Пожалуйста, скопируйте в вопрос код, задачу, тестовые данные — в общем всё, что может помочь. На скриншоте сложно что-то разобрать и невозможно скопировать.

Comment: Протестируйте на `1 3 2` `2`. Одна группа, три человека, из них 2 опоздали. Они должны выстроиться подряд в начале линейки, но программа падает с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный непонятный момент в тексте программы - метод extend. В описании   языка Python на metanit.com я такого метода не обнаружил.

Тест для 20 классов с 10-ю учащимися и K=4 прошел на "ура".
Возможные ошибки чисто из-за не соблюдения условий ввода данных,  так как никакого обработчика ошибок ввода данных в столь коротком коде просто нет.

Когда задача еще не была сформулирована,  ошибки были во множестве))

Comment: «метод extend» — https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: сябки.  Надо ходить и за пределы Метанита, оказывается))